# Looking for an easier way to create a database from a subset of another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

For testing I'm looking for a good way of pulling say 500 members out of a 300,000 member database, along with all the dependencies, and placing them into a new database. To do this originally I was using jailer but that application was creating broken SQL scripts that required manual fixing and ideally I would be able to get this all automated. Is there some better application that I missed for creating subset databases? Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at SSIS?  I'm assuming SQL Server since you tagged it sqlcmd.

Comment: No I haven't, I'll take a look now. Yeah I'm working with SQL Server, sorry I forgot to mention it.